# Security Risks of Cient-Side Password Hashing

Tags: php, javascript, security, web-applications, hash

I've read through an abundance of blog posts, tutorials, and SO questions on everything to do with proper password hashing. But I still have one question about the risks of client-side hashing.

I want to salt & hash the user's password on the client's end in JavaScript, then re-hashing & salting would be done on the server and all data is sent over HTTPS (no plain text). The hashing on the client's side would not use the same salt or algorithm as the server.

Logically to the server the user's password is a hash, so if the data transmission was in plain text it wouldn't matter if the password was hashed or not to an attacker. If the JavaScript is read, exposing the client-side hashing, **is it theoretically easier to get a hash of known length and characters (0-9 & a-f) then it is to get a password of variable length and all alphanumeric characters, upper & lowercase, and special characters?**

For example, basic MD5 hashing (I know MD5 is bad) on the client side produces a 128 bit (16 byte) hash. So, with 16 possible characters, that's 16^16 = 1.84e19 possible hashes.

With a password of length 8-10 characters, choosen from any alphanumeric or special character (by [Wikipedia's count](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_strength), that's 95). That gives 95^8 + 95^9 + 95^10, which equals 6.05e19. As you can see this is more than 3 times the amount of passwords than hashes (and this number only goes higher as you allow for passwords as long as desired).

So wouldn't it be better to not send a hashed password from the client to the server?

As a second part to this question, from readings, I understand tools such as dictionaries can be used to logically reduce this number of possibilities. Can these tools really narrow down results below the 1.84e19 combinations of the hash?

Comment: What's the point? If you're not an information security expert, don't try to be one.  Find out what the current best practices are and just do that.

Comment: Wait - you're saying that you want to hash the password, but this question is about why you're probably wrong to want to do that?  If so, in my opinion, yes. Make your sign-on page use TLS (https) and rely on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point to hashing on the client side. Then all you've done is made your application javascript dependent.

An attacker that can read the transmission can just submit the hash directly to the server anyways, never needing the typed password.

HTTPS fully protects the users password on transmission. Unless they are using a wireless keyboard in range of the clever attacker. heh.

Comment: The point would be to protect the user's password.. But good +1 for noting the fact the 3rd party listeners wouldn't need the data and could simply use the hash.